# How do I transpose the first and deepest levels of an arbitrarily nested array?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a straightforward way to convert

```
arr = {
  {a, b}, {a, b}, {{{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}, {{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}
};
```

to:

```
{{a, a, {{a, a, a}, {a, a, a}}}, {b, b, {{b, b, b}, {b, b, b}}}}
```

?

I need to swap the first and last dimension. Which should in principle be possible, because, although `arr` does not have a fixed structure, the 'bottom' is always uniform:

```
Level[arr, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}
> ```

Had `Transpose`/`Flatten`/`MapThread` accepted a negative level specification, it would have been easy. That is not the case.

One can think about that question as: How do I create `arr2` so that `arr[[whatever__,  y_]] == arr2[[y, whatever__]]`?

*EDIT:*

In general `Level[arr, {-2}]` should be a rectangular array, but rows do not need to be the same.

So this:

```
{{a1, b1}, {{{a2, b2}, {a3, b3}}, {{a4, b4}, {a5, b5}, {a6, b6}}}, {{{{a7,b7}}}} };
```

should end up:

```
{ {a1, {{a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}}, {{{a7}}} }, ...};
```

Comment: Not a solution, but `Flatten[MapIndexed[RotateRight[#2] -> #1 &, arr, {-1}]]` gives you a list of rules of what needs to be constructed. I don't know of a way to construct it though: `SparseArray` does not construct ragged structures.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `arr /. {{{a,b}->a},{{a,b}->b}}`? Or perhaps more generally, `arr /. {{a_?VectorQ :> First@a}, {a_?VectorQ :> Last@a}}`?

Comment: @Kuba maybe you can come up with a recursion that constructs the result from the list of rules I gave 4 lines up? That would be a handy tool to have in any case.

Answer (score 11):

```
arr = {{a, b}, {a, b}, {{{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}, {{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}};

SetAttributes[f1, Listable]
Apply[f1, arr, {0, -3}] /. f1 -> List
```

> {{a, a, {{a, a, a}, {a, a, a}}}, {b, b, {{b, b, b}, {b, b, b}}}}

Answer (score 3):

This is what the list at the lowest level looks like:

```
el = First@Level[list, {-2}];
```

Using this, we can solve it with a rules-based approach:

```
list /. el -> # & /@ el
```

or a recursive approach like this:

```
walk[lists : {__List}, i_] := walk[#, i] & /@ lists
walk[atoms : {__}, i_] := i
walk[list, #] & /@ el
```

Answer (score 2):

Terrible solution using `Table` but works:

```
Table[Map[#[[i]] &, arr, {-2}], {i, Last[Dimensions[Level[arr, {-2}]]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit roundabout but very versatile. First convert the structure `arr` into a list of rules, then reassemble these rules (after proper modification using `RotateRight` to transpose first and deepest levels) into a new structure.

Using the `toTree` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194276) (thanks to @b3m2a1 !):

```
arr = {{a, b}, {a, b}, {{{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}, {{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}};
toTree[Flatten[MapIndexed[RotateRight[#2] -> #1 &, arr, {-1}]]]
```

> {{a, a, {{a, a, a}, {a, a, a}}}, {b, b, {{b, b, b}, {b, b, b}}}}