# How to invert MapIndexed on a ragged structure? How to construct a tree from rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures, trees

I have an arbitrary ragged nested list-of-lists (a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))) like

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {{{e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, m}, n};
```

Its structure is given by the rules

```
B = Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 -> #1 &, A, {-1}]]
```

> {{1, 1} -> a, {1, 2} -> b, {2, 1} -> c, {2, 2} -> d, {3, 1, 1, 1} -> e, {3, 1, 1, 2} -> f, {3, 1, 1, 3} -> g, {3, 1, 1, 4} -> h, {3, 1, 1, 5} -> i, {3, 1, 2, 1} -> j, {3, 1, 2, 2} -> k, {3, 1, 2, 3} -> l, {3, 2} -> m, {4} -> n}

How can I invert this operation? How can I construct `A` solely from the information given in `B`?

---

## Edit: additional requirements

Thanks to all for contributing so far!

For robustness and versatility it would be nice for a solution to accept incomplete input like `B = {{2} -> 1}` and still generate `{0,1}`, not just `{1}`.

Also, there are some very deep trees to be constructed, like `B = {ConstantArray[2, 100] -> 1}`. A certain parsimony is required to be able to construct such trees within reasonable time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an inefficient but reasonably simple way:

```
groupMe[rules_] :=
 If[Head[rules[[1]]] === Rule,
  Values@GroupBy[
    rules,
    (#[[1, 1]] &) ->
     (If[Length[#[[1]]] === 1, #[[2]], #[[1, 2 ;;]] -> #[[2]]] &),
    groupMe
    ],
  rules[[1]]
  ]

groupMe[B]

{{a, b}, {c, d}, {{{e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, m}, n}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, b3m2a1! Your solutions of course all work, and this one I find the most appealing because of its parsimonious recursive nature. Cheers!

Comment: Your use of `Values` makes a lot of assumptions about the list `B`. Better to define something like `sortedvalues[a_Association] := Lookup[a, Range[Max[Keys[a]]], Null]`. Like this you get the same with `groupMe[B]` and `groupMe[Reverse[B]]` etc.

Comment: Recursive `GroupBy` must be the most powerful structural operator I've come across so far. Thanks for enlightening us on its use!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a procedural way:

```
Block[
 {Nothing},
 Module[
  {m = Max[Length /@ Keys[B]], arr}, 
  arr = ConstantArray[Nothing, Max /@ Transpose[PadRight[#, m] & /@ Keys[B]]];
  Map[Function[arr[[Sequence @@ #[[1]]]] = #[[2]]], B];
  arr
  ]
 ]

{{a, b}, {c, d}, {{{e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, m}, n}
```

Comment: What does the `Block[{Nothing}, ...]` wrapper do?

Comment: @Roman haven’t tested I’d it’d work without it but usually making an array of `Nothing` should become a bunch of empty lists so I figured I’d block that behavior while assigning parts.

Comment: This solution does not fill in blanks, that is, for `B={{2}->1}` it returns `{1}` instead of `{0,1}`. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a completed and cleaned-up version of [b3m2a1's recursive solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194219) based on the powerful [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) operator:

```
PositiveIntegerQ[x_] := IntegerQ[x] && Positive[x]
ruleFirst[L_ /; VectorQ[L, PositiveIntegerQ] -> _] := First[L]
ruleFirst[i_?PositiveIntegerQ -> _] := i
ruleRest[(_?PositiveIntegerQ | {_?PositiveIntegerQ}) -> c_] := c
ruleRest[L_ /; VectorQ[L, PositiveIntegerQ] -> c_] := Rest[L] -> c
sortedValues[a_Association] := Lookup[a, Range[Max[Keys[a]]], 0]
toTree[rules : {___, _Rule, ___}] :=
  sortedValues@GroupBy[Cases[rules, _Rule], ruleFirst -> ruleRest, toTree]
toTree[rule_Rule] := toTree[{rule}]
toTree[c_List] := Last[c]
toTree[c_] := c
toTree[] = toTree[{}] = {};
```

This solution mirrors many of `SparseArray`'s capabilities, like setting unmentioned (but necessary) elements to zero:

```
toTree[5 -> 1]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}

It also cleans up conflicting entries, only keeping the deepest one, or the last one if there are equivalent entries:

```
toTree[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2}]
```

> {2}

```
toTree[{{1, 2} -> 3, 1 -> 1}]
```

> {{0, 3}}

Unlike the solutions that work by selective pruning a huge high-rank tensor, this solution only constructs what is needed. For this reason it can work out situations like

```
toTree[ConstantArray[2, 100] -> 1]
```

> {0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,{0,1}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

Can you think of any other edge cases that need to be considered?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a convoluted way using pattern replacements:

```
DeleteCases[
 With[{m = Max[Length /@ Keys[B]]},
  Array[
    List,
    Max /@ Transpose[PadRight[#, m] & /@ Keys[B]]
    ] /.
   Map[
    Fold[
       Insert[
         {#, ___}, 
         _, 
         Append[ConstantArray[1, #2], -1]] &,
        #[[1]], 
       Range[m - Length[#[[1]]]]
       ] -> #[[2]] &, 
    B
    ]
  ],
 {__Integer},
 Infinity
 ]

{{a, b}, {c, d}, {{{e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, m}, n}
```

Comment: This solution does not fill in blanks, that is, for `B={{2}->1}` it returns `{1}` instead of `{0,1}`. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more functional (but memory-inefficient) version where no temporary variables are used. In the meantime the readability is "manageable". It works mostly like [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1)'s [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194224/17).

First a helper function `branch`:

```
branch = Through@*{##}&
```

The main function `ruleRevert` is defined as the following:

```
ruleRevert = RightComposition[
     branch[
             ReplacePart
           , (* make a rectangular array compatible with B: *)
             RightComposition[
                    Keys
                  , (* find max size of each level: *)
                    MapIndexed[#2[[2]] -> #1 &, #, {-1}] &, Merge[Max], KeySort, Values
                  , (* make rectangular array : *)
                    ConstantArray[Inactive[Sequence][], #] &
                  ]
           ]
   , (* replace elements in rect-array with corresponding elements in B: *)
     Apply @ Construct
   , (* remove extra Inactive[Sequence][] : *)
     Activate
   ]
```

It's easy to verify

```
ruleRevert[B] == A
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks Silvia! Your solution does not fill in blanks, that is, for `ruleRevert[{{2}->1}]` it returns `{1}` instead of `{0,1}`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Roman Good point. But shouldn't `{0,1}` be corresponding to `{{1}->0,{2}->1}` (through `Flatten[MapIndexed[#2->#1&,{0,1},{-1}]]`)? In that case we do have `ruleRevert[{{1}->0,{2}->1}] == {0,1}`..

Comment: I agree with you. The idea is to add a bit of flexibility and fault tolerance.

Comment: @Roman I tried removing `{1, 1} -> a` in `B` from your question. I think the main issue here is that it's hard to tell the shape/depth of the unspecified part. But if we restrict it to the most shallow level, something like `ReplaceRepeated` with proper pattern should do the trick. (It's very late here, maybe I shall review it tomorrow.)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
toTree[l_]:=Quiet[GatherBy[Keys[l],Table[With[{i=i},Function[Part[Slot[1],i]]],
                  {i,Max[Length/@Keys[l]]}]]/.l//.List[x_]->x]
```

seems to meet OP's requirements, and has passed a tiny battery of tests.  Wrapping the rhs in `Quiet` suppresses some complaints that `Part` makes when digging too deeply into the leaves of the tree.

Comment: Hi Mark, your solution doesn't work on `A={0}` and `B={{1}->0}`: on `toTree[B]` it returns `0`.

Comment: Well, I'm not terribly surprised, I only gave it a few tests.  If I have any more time to waste ( :-) ) on this I'll have another look.